# using session id on run time can data be filtered in tableau

Tags: shiny, visualization, tableau-api

for example a user sign-in to his account, using that using session id on run time can data be filtered in tableau dashboard. or Rshiny is good choice in that scenario.

In my point view or understanding tableau's filter cannot work like that not sure about R shiny also.